# Change confirm dialogue on submit

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

I would like to display different confirm dialogue based on events. I have two radio buttons, true or false. And current I have code in my views like this:

```
<%= form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: registration_path(resource_name), html: { method: :put }) do |f| %>
<table>
 <tr>
  <td>User Fee?</td>
  <td>
  <%= radio_button("user", "need_subscription", "true", class: "subscription_button") %>
  <%= radio_button("user", "need_subscription", "false", class: "cancel_subscription_button") %>
   </td>
  </tr>
</table>
<%= f.submit "Save", data: { confirm: 'foo?' } %>
<% end %>
```

Currently I am display confirm dialogue `foo` no matter which radio button i choose and submit. How can I set different messages in 3 different conditions like this:

1) When my default radio button is true, and I set to false. Display `foo`.

2) When my default radio button is false and I set to true. Display `bar`.

3) When my default radio button has the same value as I submit. Do not display confirm dialogue.

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 0):

Try doing it through jquery

```
var confirm = ($("#"+radio_name).val() == "true")
    ? "foo"
    : "bar";

$(".submit_button_class").data("confirm", confirm);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but this does not satisfy my third condition. Any idea how can I return nothing if the default value has not changed?